# need to render several html snippets in different places inside a hamlet template

Tags: yesod, hamlet

in my `default-layout.hamlet`:

`!!!
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>#{pageTitle pc}
    ^{pageHead pc}
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
        ????
      <div id="content">
        ^{pageBody pc}`

from a handler function, I need to replace the `????` above with some HTML contents.

how is this done?

thanks for any input.

EDIT:

I am looking for functionality similar to, for example, django's template blocks. I can define a block inside a template and the handler that uses this template for rendering, can fill in the template's blocks with the needed contents. Right now, yesod has effectively a single block in a template's body. that "defined" by the call `^{pageBody pc}`. I know I can build up the output generated by `pageBody` any way I want using `addWidget` etc., but right now I will need to output my `<div id="header">` and `<div id="content">` too and I want to avoid that because all my handlers will have to output these `div`'s to have the same markup structure in all the pages.

Comment: Any reason #{...} interpolation won't work?

Comment: would you please give me an example how to use it?

Comment: You said "some HTML contents." I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if you had a variable called `foo` of type `Html`, then you could just replace ???? with `#{foo}`.

Comment: to render my variable in default-layout.hamlet I need to define this variable in my foundation type's defaultLayout. if I do that, interpolation works. I am looking for a way to define this variable in my handler and still use it in the default-layout.hamlet. I would like to have the common HTML structure in the default-layout.hamlet, which handlers will fill in as they need.

Comment: Why can't you define the variable inside the defaultLayout function? I'm not entirely certain what you're going for here, can you perhaps expand your question to make it clearer?

Comment: as I said, I was looking for a way to render HTML from my handlers in several different places inside the default template. I have updated the question. I am not a native english speaker, sorry if I am not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is to define a function besides defaultLayout. The only thing that's magical about defaultLayout is that subsites (e.g., auth) and error messages use it by default. But you could define a "myDefaultLayout" that takes the other pieces of content you want. You could even define a helper function that wraps up the extra blocks into a single block and then passes that to defaultLayout.